# Output PDF data from array variable to output stream in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF Soap-compliant service that generates a pdf document using a third-party library. The pdf data is returned as a byte[] array and is never persisted to disk. An example interface looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
        int PdfAnswerSheets(
            out byte[] PdfData,
            out int byteLength,
            int quizId,
            string footerLine1,
            string footerLine2,
            string footerLine3,
            string tableHeaderLine,
            string quizTitle,
            string contentLicensedToName,
            string locale,
            bool withCues ,            
            string authId);
```

The service is working fine and returns data as expected.

Next, I have PHP that functions as a client to the service described above. The fundamental idea is that the PHP makes a request to the service, then sends the PDF data to the client browser **as a download**. The aim (very deliberately) is to make all of this work dynamically and without, for example, having to persist a copy of the PDF to disk and reference it by a temporary URL, etc.

This is how the PHP looks

**Function that consumes the WCF service**. This seems to work fine.

```
// Get answer sheets (web service call)
function wcfAS($quizId, $footerLine1, $footerLine2, $footerLine3, 
        $tableHeaderLine, $quizTitle, $contentLicensedToName,
        $locale, $withCues, $authId)
{
    $client = new SoapClient('http://192.168.241.91:8080/QuizSheetsSvc.svc?wsdl');

    $obj->quizId = $quizId;
    $obj->footerLine1 = $footerLine1;
    $obj->footerLine2 = $footerLine2;
    $obj->footerLine3 = $footerLine3;
    $obj->tableHeaderLine = $tableHeaderLine;
    $obj->quizTitle = $quizTitle;
    $obj->contentLicensedToName = $contentLicensedToName;
    $obj->locale = $locale;
    //$obj->modePreview = false;
    $obj->withCues = $withCues;
    $obj->authId = $authId;

    $retval = $client->PdfAnswerSheets($obj);

    return $retval;
}
```

**Function that triggers the download.**

```
function AsDownload($quizId, $footerLine1, $footerLine2, $footerLine3, 
        $tableHeaderLine, $quizTitle, $contentLicensedToName,
        $locale, $withCues, $authId)
{
    // Get the response
    $svcResponse = wcfAs($quizId, $footerLine1, $footerLine2, $footerLine3, 
        $tableHeaderLine, $quizTitle, $contentLicensedToName,
        $locale, $withCues, $authId);

    if (!empty($svcResponse->PdfData))
    {
        EchoPdfDownload($svcResponse->PdfData, 'AnswerSheets-'.$quizId.'.pdf', $svcResponse->byteLength);
    }
}
```

**Function that handles the output to browser**

```
function EchoPdfDownload($data, $fileName, $dataLength)
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.$dataLength);

    ob_clean();

    echo $data;
}
```

The problem I having is with the last part, i.e. writing the binary data to the output stream and getting a download in the browser that matches with data provided by the WCF service.

--Using the **EchoPdfDownload** implementation above, I get a download file in the browser which is significantly-inflated (around 160%) in size and corrupt. Smells like some kind of encoding or translation issue that is occurring along the way
--I have tried modifying   **EchoPdfDownload** to use PHP's unpack() method on the $data, before echo-ing it out. In this case, I get no download at all
--I have tried various other techniques with little success.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:  I tried to modified the Download function like this, and instead of getting an inflated-size pdf, I now get a download of exactly 1-byte long in the browser:

```
function EchoPdfDownload($data, $fileName, $dataLength)
{
    $binarydata = pack("C*", $data);
    $len = count($binarydata);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.$len);

    ob_clean();

    echo $binarydata;
}
```

**EDIT #2**:  Tried to workaround the issue by returning a Base64 encoded $ from the Service, decoding it on the PHP side, and then echo'ing out the data. This has brought me back to my original problem, i.e. an inflated, corrupted download. Seems increasingly likely that the issue is something to do with how the binary data is transmitted as part of the output response.

```
function EchoPdfDownload($data, $fileName, $dataLength)
{
    // Decode the data from Base64
    $decoded = base64_decode($data, true);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: '.$len);

    ob_clean();

    echo $decoded;

    ob_end_flush();
}
```

Finally, I should mention that the AJAX on the client-side looks like this, in case it be relevant:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#dwnAS").click(function(d){
        d.preventDefault();

        var ASreqtype = "AS";
        var ASfooterLine1 = $("#footerText1").val();
        var ASfooterLine2 = $("#footerText2").val();
        var ASfooterLine3 = $("#footerText3").val();
        var AStableHeaderLine  = $("#tableCaption").val();
        var ASquizTitle = $("#quizTitle").val();
        var ASwithCues  = $("#withCues").val();

        if (ASquizTitle=='')
        {
            alert("Please specify a quiz title");
        }
        else
        {
            //disable the submission controls
            $("#dwnAS").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#dwnMS").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#dwnTB").attr("disabled", true);

            var postData = 
                'type=' + ASreqtype
                + '&quizId=' + '<?php echo $quizId; ?>'
                + '&footerLine1=' + encodeURIComponent(ASfooterLine1)
                + '&footerLine2=' + encodeURIComponent(ASfooterLine2)
                + '&footerLine3=' + encodeURIComponent(ASfooterLine3)
                + '&tableHeaderLine=' + encodeURIComponent(AStableHeaderLine)
                + '&quizTitle=' + encodeURIComponent(ASquizTitle)
                + '&contentLicensedToName=' + '<?php echo urlencode($contentLicensedToName) ; ?>'
                + '&locale=' + '<?php echo $locale; ?>'
                + '&withCues=' + ASwithCues
                + '&authId=' + '<?php echo urlencode($authId); ?>' ;

            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "subscriber-download-post.php",
                data: postData,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response, status, xhr){

                    $("#dwnAS").attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#dwnMS").attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#dwnTB").attr("disabled", false);

                    downloadresponse(response, status, xhr);

                },
                error: function(response){
                    $("#dwnAS").attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#dwnMS").attr("disabled", false);
                    $("#dwnTB").attr("disabled", false);

                    alert("The download failed. Please try again later.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
)
}) //$(document).ready(function(){

function downloadresponse(response, status, xhr) {
        // check for a filename
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            }

            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was not a PHP issue at all, but instead, an issue with receiving binary data with the jQuery "ajax" call. Where you have a need to receive binary data over an ajax call, you have to use a Binary Transport.

More details at this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/879517/Encoding-AJAX-binary-response?arn=1